# Show buttons, date range picker and labels in one line without space

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to align the label, buttons, and date range picker in one line so that it will look good.
Here is my code. I tried doing it but does not help to align and look good. it would be great if you can guide me. Thank you.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.5/daterangepicker.css" integrity="sha512-gp+RQIipEa1X7Sq1vYXnuOW96C4704yI1n0YB9T/KqdvqaEgL6nAuTSrKufUX3VBONq/TPuKiXGLVgBKicZ0KA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.5/daterangepicker.min.js" integrity="sha512-mh+AjlD3nxImTUGisMpHXW03gE6F4WdQyvuFRkjecwuWLwD2yCijw4tKA3NsEFpA1C3neiKhGXPSIGSfCYPMlQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.5/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-i2CVnAiguN6SnJ3d2ChOOddMWQyvgQTzm0qSgiKhOqBMGCx4fGU5BtzXEybnKatWPDkXPFyCI0lbG42BnVjr/Q==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
      <label style="font-weight: normal !important;"> Date range :</label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 input-group" style="float:left;">
      <input type="text" name="daterange" class="form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyyy - mm/dd/yyyy" />
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
    </div>

    <div class='col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12'>
      <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" id="btnSearch" type="button"><span class="fa fa-search"></span>
                Search</button>
    </div>
    <div class='col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12'>
      <button type="button" id="btnClearSearch" class="btn btn-primary">Clear Search</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

my output:
[image]

What I want is :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

put label and rang in one col and buttons in another col

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.5/daterangepicker.css" integrity="sha512-gp+RQIipEa1X7Sq1vYXnuOW96C4704yI1n0YB9T/KqdvqaEgL6nAuTSrKufUX3VBONq/TPuKiXGLVgBKicZ0KA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.5/daterangepicker.min.js" integrity="sha512-mh+AjlD3nxImTUGisMpHXW03gE6F4WdQyvuFRkjecwuWLwD2yCijw4tKA3NsEFpA1C3neiKhGXPSIGSfCYPMlQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.5/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-i2CVnAiguN6SnJ3d2ChOOddMWQyvgQTzm0qSgiKhOqBMGCx4fGU5BtzXEybnKatWPDkXPFyCI0lbG42BnVjr/Q==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

  

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 input-group" style="float:left;">
       <label style="font-weight: normal !important;" class="mr-2"> Date range :</label>
      <input type="text" name="daterange" class="form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyyy - mm/dd/yyyy" />
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
    </div>

    <div class='col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pl-0'>
      <button class="btn btn-default pull-right mr-2" id="btnSearch" type="button"><span class="fa fa-search"></span>
                Search</button>
      <button type="button" id="btnClearSearch" class="btn btn-primary">Clear Search</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the padding for all your `<div>` columns which will remove the space between them. For example:

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" style="padding:0px;">
  <label style="font-weight: normal !important;"> Date range :</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. For your required output, we have removed bootstrap grid classes (`row`,`col-*`). With the help of flex utilities, we can easily fulfill the requirement, this solution works well also in responsive.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/dk1my978/

```css
.date-selection>* {
  margin: 6px;
}

.input-box label {
  margin-right: 6px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
}

.input-box input {
  min-width: 280px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.5/daterangepicker.css" integrity="sha512-gp+RQIipEa1X7Sq1vYXnuOW96C4704yI1n0YB9T/KqdvqaEgL6nAuTSrKufUX3VBONq/TPuKiXGLVgBKicZ0KA==" crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.5/daterangepicker.min.js" integrity="sha512-mh+AjlD3nxImTUGisMpHXW03gE6F4WdQyvuFRkjecwuWLwD2yCijw4tKA3NsEFpA1C3neiKhGXPSIGSfCYPMlQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.5/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-i2CVnAiguN6SnJ3d2ChOOddMWQyvgQTzm0qSgiKhOqBMGCx4fGU5BtzXEybnKatWPDkXPFyCI0lbG42BnVjr/Q==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="date-selection d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center">

    <div class="input-box d-flex align-items-center">
      <label style="font-weight: normal !important;"> Date range :</label>
      <input type="text" name="daterange" class="form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyyy - mm/dd/yyyy" />
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
    </div>


    <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" id="btnSearch" type="button"><span class="fa fa-search"></span>
      Search</button>
    <button type="button" id="btnClearSearch" class="btn btn-primary">Clear Search</button>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Yudiz Solutions for the solution but it looks totally stretched.
Do I need to install any plugin for flex?

Comment: You don't require to install any plugin for flex, because it is flex utilities provided by bootstrap itself. We have given min-width to the input element in CSS for a better experience, you can change the value of min-width according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Answer :

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-12 form-group form-inline">
            <label style="font-weight: normal !important;"> Date range :</label>
            <div class="input-group col-md-3">
                <input type="text" name="daterange" class="form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyyy - mm/dd/yyyy">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-default" id="btnSearch" type="button"><span class="fa fa-search"></span>
                Search</button>
            <button type="button" id="btnClearSearch" class="btn btn-primary">Clear Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```